# Share MS Access 2010 database over the internet

Tags: microsoft-access

Is it possible to access MS Access 2010 database over the internet without using Sharepoint or similar services? I have a server where I want to put the back end and email the front end to various people. As I understand this is easy if all the users are on the local network. But how do I share my database over the internet? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access 2010 is a file-based database.  Thus the only way to share it with a separate front-end / back-end database (linked tables) setup is if you expose the file share on the Internet.  This is most definitely **NOT** a good idea.

Even if you use a VPN to add security you will probably find performance unacceptable.  The only realistic solution is to use a SQL Server back-end and link to that from the MS Access front-end databases.

Comment: You don't *have* to use SQL Server at the back-end. Access as a front-end should work with any ODBC connection, so the back-end could be any DBMS (including SQLite, for argument's sake).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although sharing it is not a good idea, I would like to know how I can do it. Any suggestions how I can do it?

Comment: Access doesn't like too many connections, so be wary of this.

Comment: @Baha you can ONLY do this by exposing a file share on the Internet.  You would likely need to remove any firewalls and probably also add a port-mapping rule.  Even once you've done all of that performance will likely be unacceptable.

Comment: @Randolph - yes of course, any non-file based database engine will do (e.g. not SQL CE either) just as long as it can be connected to over a TCP port.

Answer (score 1):

Host the app on Windows Terminal Server.